# How do I fix the DISABLE TRIGGER permission denied in database error?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, permission-denied

I am doing maintenance on a legacy ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL Server web application. A particular feature is broken. Checking the log file reveals the following error:

```
Error: SqlException (262): Procedure: spMyStoredProcedure Line: 10 State: 20 Message: DISABLE TRIGGER permission denied in database 'MyDatabase'.
```

The stored procedure code is:

```
ALTER Procedure dbo.spMyStoredProcedure
as
    --Disable Triggers, no need to copy records into history tables
    Disable TRIGGER Trigger1 on myschema.table1;
    Disable TRIGGER Trigger2 on myschema.table2;
    Disable TRIGGER Trigger3 on myschema.table3;
    Disable TRIGGER Trigger4 on myschema.table4;
```

The user account being used for the database connection has been given the following roles:

[image: SQL Server roles]

How do I fix this?

Comment: db_ddladmin should be enough as you need alter permission on the table. Just to confirm that there's nothing funny going on, look at sys.fn_my_permisssions for the tables in question. You might see something surprising. Alternatively, ensure that you're running as who you think you are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The user account required access to **myschema**. Making the user an owner of **myschema** through Database User dialog box in SQL Server Management Studio resolved the error.

Comment: there is no need for that, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22137339/1501497) is enough

Answer (score 5):

To disable or enable trigger The user must have `ALTER` permission on the Table or the View on which trigger was defined/created.

To grant permission to the user on the table you can execute the following statement.

```
GRANT ALTER ON [dbo].[theTable] TO [User] 
GO
```